# Set previous row value based on current row in pandas dataframe when iterating over rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where additional information is stored on a new row (data extracted from a poorly formatted PDF).

If the `Amount` column is empty, I'd like to copy the value in `Transaction details` to the `Type` column in the previous row.
A nice to have would be if if it could also trim the `Purchase` section, as I only want the `Purchase` title and drop the old row.

Current dataframe:

| Date | Transaction details | Amount | Balance | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Round up to Round-up | -0.77 | 3344.67 |  |
|  | Transfer |  |  |  |
| 01 Dec 2022 | School | -12.01 | 3332.66 |  |
|  | Purchase EUR 13.87 FX rate £1 = €1.1549 |  |  |  |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Round up to Round-up | -0.67 | 3331.99 |  |
|  | Transfer |  |  |  |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Restaurant | -21.39 | 3310.6 |  |
|  | Purchase EUR 24.70 FX rate £1 = €1.1547 |  |  |  |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Round up to Round-up | -0.75 | 3309.85 |  |
|  | Transfer |  |  |  |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Shop | -48.64 | 3261.21 |  |
|  | Purchase EUR 56.18 FX rate £1 = €1.1550 |  |  |  |

Ideal result:

| Date | Transaction details | Amount | Balance | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Round up to Round-up | -0.77 | 3344.67 | Transfer |
| 01 Dec 2022 | School | -12.01 | 3332.66 | Purchase |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Round up to Round-up | -0.67 | 3331.99 | Transfer |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Restaurant | -21.39 | 3310.6 | Purchase |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Round up to Round-up | -0.75 | 3309.85 | Transfer |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Shop | -48.64 | 3261.21 | Purchase |
| 01 Dec 2022 | Am | -6.06 | 3255.15 | Purchase |

I have attempted a few variations of the `shift(-1)` and also the below code, but I can't seem to get the result I'd like.

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df[df['Transaction details'].str.contains("Transfer|Purchase")==True]:
        df.loc[i-1, 'Type'] = df.loc[i, 'Transaction details']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can denote types in the former rows (where they reside), then perform backward filling and delete the unneeded (with empty `Amount`) rows in the end:

```
m = df['Amount'] == ''
df['Type'] = np.where(m, df['Transaction details'].str.split().str[0], df['Type'])
df['Type'] = df['Type'].fillna(method='bfill')
df = df[~m]
```

---

```
           Date   Transaction details Amount  Balance      Type
0   01 Dec 2022  Round up to Round-up  -0.77  3344.67  Transfer
2   01 Dec 2022                School -12.01  3332.66  Purchase
4   01 Dec 2022  Round up to Round-up  -0.67  3331.99  Transfer
6   01 Dec 2022            Restaurant -21.39  3310.60  Purchase
8   01 Dec 2022  Round up to Round-up  -0.75  3309.85  Transfer
10  01 Dec 2022                  Shop -48.64  3261.21  Purchase
```

Comment: Hello Roman, I do have a very basic question. How can I reproduce this `|` separated sample data? possibly with StringIO and `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, hello. When you select a formatted rows (as they eventually appear in the question) it should not copy with `|`. (that's how I copied it). Then: `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')`. But there could be cases when you need to manually arrange whitespace gaps, the rows with multiple arbitrary empty fields are problematic to reflect

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes it worked. Normally there is more than 2 white space between values.